# OK. Weirdest thing ever. Laptop screen turns off when printing

Tags: xubuntu, printing

I re-purposed an older Acer Aspire laptop my brother had and installed Xubuntu 14.04. It works perfectly well except for one problem he told me yesterday:

The screen turns off when he prints.

Yeah. I haven't ever heard anything like that before, nor apparently many else, since google turns up nothing.

To top it off, the screen doesn't turn on unless he does a cold reboot with the power button. It *does* still print fine and all, but just that the laptop monitor turns off when he hits print. I have no clue anymore.

Comment: This is probably one of those issues that will never get understood. In an attempt to create a workaround (if possible at all), can you run from a terminal this script: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1155139/xr.sh (copy it into a file, save it as `xr.sh`, then run from a terminal the command: `/bin/bash /path/to/xr.sh` )? *Then* print some file. If the screen blacks out, immediately restart and post the ***last*** 20 lines  or so of `~/xroutput` into your question.

Comment: I will do that once I get access to that computer - my brother lives some distance away and I can't get there anytime I want. And my brother himself isn't the most apt computer person out there ;) (so making him run scripts is out of the question.)